# Count number of rows with a p-value equal to, or lower than 0.05

Tags: r, data-analysis, statistical-test

I am new to R programming. I am facing issues which solving this:

Dataset:

```
set.seed(897)
ME <- matrix(rnorm(24000),nrow=1000)
colnames(ME) <- c(paste("A",1:12,sep=""),paste("B",1:12,sep=""))
```

Use apply() to calculate a statistical test for every row in ME. You want to ask whether the groups A and B are from the same population or from populations with different means. You can assume data to be normally distributed.
Count the number of rows with a p-value equal to, or lower than 0.05.

I tried 
`>P<- apply(ME , 1 , function(ME){ t.test(ME[1:1000])$p.value })`
 `> length(which(P <= 0.05))`
 frown emoticon but this is incorrect

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yep , I tried it `P<- apply(ME , 1 , function(ME){ t.test(ME[1:1000])$p.value })`   `length(which(P <= 0.05))` frown emoticon but this is incorrect

Comment: Please check the code in my solution.  You are only passing  single argument inside the `t.test`.  Also, the `ME[1:1000]` is not correct as there are only 24 columns.  So, within each row, the length is only 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column names are not in a particular order, then we can use `grep` to find the index of column names that start with `A` and also with `B`.

```
 ind1 <- grep('^A', colnames(ME))
 ind2 <- grep('^B', colnames(ME))
```

Then we do the `t.test` by row using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

```
 pval <- apply(ME, 1, FUN=function(x) t.test(x[ind1], x[ind2])$p.value)
 head(pval)
 #[1] 0.4987050 0.0303736 0.7143174 0.2955703 0.5082427 0.2109010
```

We get a logical index by comparing with 0.05

```
 v1 <- pval <= 0.05
```

Get the `sum` of the `TRUE` values to find the number of rows that have `p.value` less than 0.05

```
sum(v1)
#[1] 55
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun , but in `pval <- apply(ME, 1, FUN=function(x) t.test(x[ind1], x[ind2])$p.value)`   , In this I have to replace x with ME ?  I am getting error when i tried to execute this command

Comment: @andrahul Using the example you provided, I am not getting any error.  Why you want to replace `x` with `ME`?

Comment: @andrahul Are you using the same example?  What is the error message?

Comment: It was an error due to my workspace , i resolved that issue

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: @andrahul Thanks for the feedback.  Glad to help you.